# Delete files when their associated record on DB has been removed in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table named **userfiles** that stores path of users uploaded files:

```
Userfiles table :
 file_id
 path
 user_id
 created_at
 updated_at
```

Now I want to delete related file on the disk Immediately file record on database has been removed. All files are in `public/upload/userfiles` path.

I wrote this function in userfile model:

```
public static function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();

            static::deleted(function($file)
            {
                $directory  =   public_path('upload/userfiles/');

                $path   =   $file->path;

                if (File::exists($directory.$path)) {
                    File::delete($directory.$path);
                }
            });
        }
```

But real file does not remove.
I think that an error occurs when deleting record and file because file record on DB does not remove while before adding this function that does.

I do not even know how to see what error occurred.
How can I solve this?

Comment: check $file array is getting on deleted function.

Comment: Debug your code and find out the reason. May be `File::exists` fails because you miss some slash or something.

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny, how Can I debug? for test I return a string from `deleted()` method but it does not return any value because I think it work in the behind.

Comment: Use PHPStorm or any other IDE debugger, setup a breakpoint... Dump information into some file and inspect it.... Do whatever is needed to find out why your piece of code does not get called.